# Why is my stored procedure not running correctly?

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

I have an asp.net 4.0 app hitting a sql 2008 db. I have a very basic stored proc designed to return records. It works when I execute it in the .net ide server explorer. But when I step through the .net code, even though the variable is being passed in the way I like (and have done many imes before), nothing is being returned. Here is the stored proc...

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE get_cases_by_search_criteria
    @vin as varchar(50) = null

AS
declare @sqlstr varchar(5000)

set @sqlstr = 'SELECT 
                [Case].CaseID, 
                [Case].VIN, 
                [Case].Make, 
                [Case].Model, 
                Contact.FirstName, 
                Contact.LastName, 
                FROM  [Case] INNER JOIN
                Contact ON [Case].CaseID = Contact.CaseID 
                Where Contact.ContactTypeID = 1 '

                if  @vin is not null and @vin <> ''
                BEGIN
                    set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' and ' + ('[Case].VIN = ''' + convert(varchar,@vin) + '''') 
                END

exec(@sqlstr)
```

And here is how I pass in the values...

```
        'non-specific parameter
        param1 = oFactory.CreateParameter()
        param1.ParameterName = "@vin"
        param1.DbType = DbType.String
        param1.Value = oSearchCriteria.VIN
        oCmd.Parameters.Add(param1)

        oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        oCmd.CommandText = "get_cases_by_search_criteria"

        Using (oConnection)
            oConnection.Open()
            oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader()

            While oReader.Read
```

Comment: can you exec it SQL Management studio and PRINT the @sqlstr?  it might help you establish if the select statement is at fault.

Comment: nothing wrong with you code that I can see.  Perhaps try adding the parameter all in one statement   oCmd.Parameters.Add("@vin", oSearchCriteria.VIN, DbType.String)

Comment: If I print it out and prints out (after passing in a valid paramter for VIN) exactly as I would expect. And, when I copy and paste that into the sql editor, it runs and RETURNS the records!

Comment: Are you using a SQLDataAdapter to read the disconected record set?

Comment: Are you *sure* your web.config is pointed to the correct server and database?  Also, can you use SQL Profiler to watch the database server to ensure the query is going to it?

Comment: As a side note, this stored procedure is vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when `@vin` equals `'; DROP DATABASE UserDB; --` ?

This might not be the problem you were looking to solve, but the way you're using dynamic SQL makes you vulnerable to a [SQL Injection Attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Instead of using `exec(@sql)` string, you should use `sp_executesql`, and parameterize `@vin`

```
DECLARE @sqlstr varchar(5000)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)

SET @sqlstr  = 'SELECT 
                [Case].CaseID, 
                [Case].VIN, 
                [Case].Make, 
                [Case].Model, 
                Contact.FirstName, 
                Contact.LastName, 
                FROM  [Case] INNER JOIN
                Contact ON [Case].CaseID = Contact.CaseID 
                Where Contact.ContactTypeID = 1 '

IF  @vin is not null and @vin <> ''
BEGIN
    SET @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' and [Case].VIN = @vinparm'
END

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@vinparm varchar(50)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlstr, @ParmDefinition, @vinparm = @vin
```